# How to validate parameters of dialogflow from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I have a node.js backend connected to dialogflow to make a chatbot, and I can send answers, read inputs from users. Sometimes I need to validate some parameters as the IDCARD number. Well, I can retrieve a message to the user saying that the ID number is not correct, but I need to stay in the same dialogflow context and not go to the next one to be able to keep the new value in the same parameter. Does anyone know how to do that?
This could also be useful to add a previous button when sending quick responses, to go back to the previous question.

I leave you my code, where I read a context parameter and validate it:

```
case "ingresar-telefono":

        let filteredContexts = contexts.filter(function (el)
        {
            return el.name.includes('recibirinfo')
        });

        if (filteredContexts.length > 0 && contexts[0].parameters) {

            numerotelefonico = (isDefined(contexts[0].parameters.fields['Telefono.original']) && contexts[0].parameters.fields['Telefono.original'] !== '') ? contexts[0].parameters.fields['Telefono.original'].stringValue: '';
            console.log("Numero telefonico: "+numerotelefonico);

            if (isNaN(numerotelefonico)){
                console.log("Entro is not a number.");
                sendTextMessage(sender, "¡Parece que tu numero de telefono tiene caracteres no permitidos!");
                sendTextMessage(sender, "¡Vuelvelo a ingresar!");

            }

            else if(!numerotelefonico.startsWith("9")){
                console.log("Entro no empieza en 9.");
                sendTextMessage(sender, "¡Vuelvelo a ingresar!");
            }

            else{
                handleMessages(messages, sender);
            }

        }
        break;
```

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you handle this by removing the output context from the intent in the Dialogflow UI. Once you've detected that the provided ID number is correct you can then set the output context to the one that you removed. If the provided ID number is incorrect you set the output context to the input context of that intent and reply with "Please provide a valid ID". This will make sure that the user is prompted again to provide a valid ID.

You could then create another intent 'forgottenID' with the same input context with a few trainingsphrases "I don't know", "I don't have one",... where you then explain the user how to get a valid ID or what to do once they've forgotten their ID.

Contexts can be set like this:

```
agent.context.set({
  'name':'context-name',
  'lifespan': 5,
  'parameters':{
    'parameter-name':'parameter-value'
    }
});
```

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thank you @Mathias Schrooten, it makes sense to me, but do you know how you can set a dialogflow context from node.js ? Thank you

Comment: I've added a way to set contexts in my answer! @JonathanPrieto